# How to get parent embedded struct field value?

Tags: go

I have the following struct in my package.

```
type Animal struct {
  Id string
  // and some more common fields
}
```

A user who uses my package should be able to implement own `Animal`s. As I need `Id` in one of my methods the user has to embed my struct.

```
type Dog struct {
  Animal
  Name string
  Legs int
}
```

In my package I have a `save()` function that saves `Animal`s to database. As I don't know the user's type I have to use `interface{}` as argument type. My question is: How do I get the `Id` (from the parent struct `Animal`)? At the moment I use some JSON parsing and unmarshalling, but is this the way to go/Go?

```
func put(doc interface{}) error {
  res, err := json.Marshal(doc)
  if err != nil {
    return err
  }
  var animal *Animal
  err = json.Unmarshal(res, &animal)
  if err != nil {
    return err
  }
  fmt.Println(animal.Id) // finally I have the Id
  // ...
}
```

Usage

```
func main() {
  bello := Dog{
    Animal: Animal{
      Id: "abcd1234",
    },
    Name: "bello",
    Legs: 4,
  }
  err := put(bello)
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you can add an interface in order to be sure to get a reference to the parent struct:

```
type AnimalGetter interface {
    GetAnimal() *Animal
}

func (dog *Dog) GetAnimal() *Animal {
    return &dog.Animal
}
```

That would allow your save method to do a type assertion (AnimalGetter):

```
func save(obj interface{}) {
    animal := obj.(AnimalGetter)
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", animal.GetAnimal())
}
```

See a complete example in <kbd>[play.golang.org](http://play.golang.org/p/vPlEKn5ZhX)</kbd>.

Output:

```
&{{dogid} wouf 0}
&{dogid}
```

Simpler:

```
func save(animal AnimalGetter) {
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", animal.GetAnimal())
}
```

(<kbd>[play.golang.org](http://play.golang.org/p/UinWPcJGi4)</kbd>)

Comment: Why not just have `save(AnimalGetter)` and save the casting?

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer sure, I was simply using the same signature as the one mention in the question (`put` or `save(interface{})`. I have edited the answer following your suggestion.

Comment: Minor nitpick: the getter should be called `Animal()`, not `GetAnimal()` as per [Effective Go](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#Getters).

Comment: @VonC your approach can be even simplified by making the animal itself animalGetter, and then not needing to reimplement this function for each animal. here's my take on your suggestion: http://play.golang.org/p/XE9LmbPwLi

Comment: @Ainar-G I tried that (naming it `Animal()`), but it failed, with a `Dog` field `Animal` and a `Dog` method `Animal()`: the duplicated names made the compilation impossible.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer I agree, but I didn't want to simplify too much at first, re-using as much of the original question as a starting point. The main point of the answer is that you need some kind of pointer to the parent struct.

Answer (score 2):

The way to go/Go here is to declare `Animal` as an interface:

```
type Animal interface {
    ID() int
    Name() string
    // Other Animal field getters here.
}
```

Then, `save` can take `Animal` as an argument and get all the info it needs using `Animal`'s methods.

The other possbile way is to use the [`reflect`](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/) package to obtain the `Animal` fields from the struct, but this will be buggier, dirtier and possibly slower that using an interface.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with this small reflection trick, although perhaps using interfaces like @VonC suggested might be a more practical and idiomatic approach.

Anyway, here's the same achieved with reflection:

```
func main() {

    d := Dog {
        Animal { "id1111" },
        "Barky",
        4,
    }
    fmt.Println(reflect.ValueOf(d).FieldByName("Animal").Interface().(Animal))
}
```

Comment: I avoided reflection at first, preferring making the API need of getting the animal more visible. But reflection can certainly work.