# Automatic Type Assertion In Go

Tags: struct, interface, go

Take this sample of code ([playground](http://play.golang.org/p/8KR6wzXCn-)):

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
)

type Foo struct {
  Name string
}

var data = make(map[string]interface{})

func main() {
  data["foo"] = &Foo{"John"}

  foo := data["foo"].(*Foo)

  fmt.Println(foo.Name)
}
```

When I add something to `data`, the type turns into an `interface{}`, so when I later retrieve that value I have to assert the original type back onto it. Is there a way to, for example, define a getter function for `data` which will automagically assert the type?

Comment: Why not give `data` a type of its own and define a `Get(key string) *Foo` method on that type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really, unless you turn to [`reflect`](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/) and try to get the type of the interface that way.

But the idiomatic (and faster) way remains the [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) (a "type conversion" which must be checked at runtime, since `data` only contains `interface{}` values).

If data were to reference a specific interface (instead of the generic `interface{}` one), like I [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25726424/6309), then you could use a `Name()` method defined directly on it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this, but you might want to think about your design.. It is very rare that you *need* to do this kind of things.

http://play.golang.org/p/qPSxRoozaM

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type GenericMap map[string]interface{}

func (gm GenericMap) GetString(key string) string {
    return gm[key].(string)
}

func (gm GenericMap) GetFoo(key string) *Foo {
    return gm[key].(*Foo)
}

func (gm GenericMap) GetInt(key string) int {
    return gm[key].(int)
}

var data = make(GenericMap)

type Foo struct {
    Name string
}

func main() {
    data["foo"] = &Foo{"John"}

    foo := data.GetFoo("foo")

    fmt.Println(foo.Name)
}
```

You might want to add error checking, in case the key does not exists or is not the expected type.

Comment: Don't know why you got downvoted, I wouldn't do it but it's still correct.

Comment: I did, because I'm talking about 1 getter to assert the value dynamically, not a bunch of getters.

Comment: Well, it is not possible then. Unless you go full reflect, but you would be better off with an other language.

Comment: What type should that getter return? You must specify one, and only one, return type.